# How to declare multi-tenancy schema spanning datasource within Wildfly

Tags: database, mariadb, wildfly, multi-tenant, multiple-schema

Is there a way to declare a schema spanning datasource configuration within wildfly, so that the underlying database (MariaDB in this case) may consist out of n-different schemas (all with the same structure), each accessible through the defined datasource?
I am thinking about some wildcard configuration within the `connection-url` for the datasource names.

The goal is to achieve a separation of the data between multiple instances of our database schema, each for one customer in one schema.

Answer (score 0):

We have come to a solution to achieve this behaviour.
We have configured a default schema every instance connects to initially. Internally, whenever a new request is received, we have an aspect that issues a `use Schemaname` to select the correct schema.